# SQL Get Total Column from Dynamic Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have problem with getting total column from my dynamic pivot query.
From my code i got this result :
[the result without total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whqao.png)
, I want the total column from column 32,33,34,35 and place it after column 35 (vertical total column)

Here is my code :

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols =  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(DATEPART(wk,OINV.TaxDate))
            FROM OINV
            WHERE YEAR(OINV.TaxDate) = 2016 AND MONTH(OINV.TaxDate) = 8
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SELECT @colNames =  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(DATEPART(wk,OINV.TaxDate)) +', 0) as '+ QUOTENAME(DATEPART(wk,OINV.TaxDate))
                FROM OINV
                WHERE YEAR(OINV.TaxDate) = 2016 AND MONTH(OINV.TaxDate) = 8
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @query =  'SELECT Salesman, Cabang, '+ @colNames +'
          FROM(SELECT
                OSLP.SlpName as Salesman,
                OCRD.U_STEM_BP_WHSE as Cabang,
                SUM(OINV.DocTotal) as Achiev,
              DATEPART(wk,OINV.TaxDate) as WeekNo
            FROM OINV
              INNER JOIN INV1 ON INV1.DocEntry = OINV.DocEntry
              INNER JOIN OSLP ON OINV.SlpCode = OSLP.SlpCode
                INNER JOIN OITM ON INV1.ItemCode = OITM.ItemCode
                INNER JOIN OMRC ON OITM.FirmCode = OMRC.FirmCode
                INNER JOIN OCRD ON OINV.CardCode = OCRD.CardCode
            WHERE
              YEAR(OINV.TaxDate) = 2016 AND MONTH(OINV.TaxDate) = 8
            GROUP BY
              OSLP.SlpName,
              OCRD.U_STEM_BP_WHSE,
              OINV.TaxDate) AS a
          PIVOT(SUM(Achiev)
          FOR WeekNo IN (' + @cols + ')) AS pvt
          ORDER BY Salesman ASC'

EXECUTE(@query);
```

Your help is much appreciated, thank you.

Use advice from @Anton, this is updated result i got :
[the updated result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI8md.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
SET @query =  'SELECT Salesman, Cabang, '+ @colNames +'
```

To

```
SET @query =  'SELECT Salesman, Cabang, '+ @colNames +', ' + @SumCol32_35 + '
```

@SubCol32_35 should be like '[32] + [33] + [34] + [35]'

You can hardcode it if the column names are fixed, or populate it inside

```
SELECT @colNames =
```

with CASE ... END statement to populate relevant columns only.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice, and already test it to my code, the total result now appear. but the problem is when one column has a value and the other is null or zero, the total columns return to zero. The example result updated on my question.

Comment: okay, no problem, but can you help me one more about the problem on my comment above?

Comment: just add ISNULL() near each column name:  ISNULL([32], 0) + ISNULL([33], 0) + ....

Comment: Also add some alias to the new column:  ISNULL([32], 0) + .... + ISNULL([35], 0) AS Total_32_35

Comment: Many thanks bro, its worked now! you save my day! :D